# Java app hangs on in.hasNext();

Tags: java, sockets, java.util.scanner

I am working on Battleship swing app that communicates through sockets.

```
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection;
private PrintWriter out;
private Scanner in;
```

I make a connection and setup output and input streams

```
out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), true);
in = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
```

Then user clicks on field that he thinks there is a ship, and coordinates get sent

```
public void sendXY(String cord)
{
    out.print(cord);
}
```

Then the method gets called that waits for opponents app to respond if there is a ship or not (true|false).

```
public void readHit()
{
    boolean k = true;
    while(k)
    {
        if(in.hasNext()) //<--app hangs at this line
        {
            Fields.hit = in.nextBoolean();
            k = false;  
        }
    }
}
```

But when I test this, my app hangs at first call to in.hasNext().

Comment: Have you read the javadoc?

Comment: If you mean the line that says "This method may block while waiting for input to scan.", then that doesn't apply to my example because it gets next element later, but not necessarily before hasNext is first called

Comment: The print method does probably not send a complete token. My first guess would to use println. Blocking on hasNext is the preferred behaviour, the alternative would be to burn 100% CPU with while(true).

Comment: I tried using println instead, but problem persists. EDIT: I changed the sending of cord to println as well as sending of hit to println and it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scanner is waiting for a token, the print method does not send a complete token unless String cord contains some kind of terminator. Try to use println instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. Working now.

Answer (score 1):

You could first test if there are bytes available in the connection inputstream:

```
InputStream instream = connection.getInputStream();
in = new Scanner(instream);
```

Then replace

```
if(in.hasNext())
```

with

```
if (instream.available() > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

From JavaDoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()

> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not advance past any input.

Looking inside sources, we can find this:

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    ensureOpen();
    saveState();
    while (!sourceClosed) {
        if (hasTokenInBuffer())
            return revertState(true);
        readInput();
    }
    boolean result = hasTokenInBuffer();
    return revertState(result);
}
```

It looks that **method blocks if Source Stream is open and there are no bytes** available. Try to find another alternatives to solve this problem. You could try to create new thread for every client, which will call `hasNext()`

Answer (score 0):

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29):

> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This
>   method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not
>   advance past any input.