# Getting out of While(hasNextInt())

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Hi I have a problem getting out of the loop. My input (it can input any number of integer) supposed to be

```
Add 10 5 //input then after I press enter it supposed to show the output
Items added: [5, 10] //output
```

But instead I get

```
Add 10 5 //enter
Add 2 //I need to enter another input to get the output
Items added: [5, 10] //output
```

Here is my code. I think the problem is after the while loop I need to remove the remainder of the input line but I don't know how to fix it. Please help, thank you

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws NoSuchElementException {

      StackLL <Integer> stack = new StackLL <Integer> ();
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String op;

      while (sc.hasNext()) {
          op = sc.next();

          if (op.equals("Add")) {
              // Fill in the code
              while (sc.hasNextInt()){
                  stack.push(sc.nextInt());
              }   
              System.out.print("Items added: ");
              System.out.print(stack.toString() + "\n");
          }   

          else if (op.equals("Query")) {
              // Fill in the code 
              while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                  int query = sc.nextInt();
                  int pop = query - 1;
                  while (query!=pop)
                      pop = stack.pop();
              }       
              sc.nextLine();
              System.out.println("Query met: " + stack.toString());
          }   
      }   
  }
```

Comment: add `sc.nextLine()` after your while in your if

Comment: It still does not work. I still have the same problem

Comment: `while (sc.hasNextInt())` will wait until you've got something else than an integer. call `sc.nextInt()` twice instead. If you can have more than 2 integer then use sc.nextLine() and split it.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

The next() and hasNext() methods and their primitive-type companion methods (such as nextInt() and hasNextInt()) first skip any input that matches the delimiter pattern, and then attempt to return the next token. Both hasNext and next methods **may block waiting for further input**. Whether a hasNext method blocks has no connection to whether or not its associated next method will block.

Answer (score 0):

**replace**

```
   while (sc.hasNextInt()){
     stack.push(sc.nextInt());
   }
```

**with**

```
stack.push(sc.nextInt());
stack.push(sc.nextInt());
```

also you don't need  `sc.nextLine();` at end

see [hasNext() - when does it block and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873134/hasnext-when-does-it-block-and-why)