# How do I detect contents of nextInt OR if it's at the end?

Tags: java

The below problem comes from Chapter 5 of the book *Intro to Java* by Daniel Liang:

> (Count positive and negative numbers and compute the average of numbers) Write
>   a program that reads an unspecified number of integers, determines how many
>   positive and negative values have been read, and computes the total and average of
>   the input values (not counting zeros). Your program ends with the input 0. Display
>   the average as a floating-point number.
>  
>   
>   Here is a sample run:
>   Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: 1 2 -1 3 0
>   The number of positives is 3
>   The number of negatives is 1
>   The total is 5.0
>   The average is 1.25
>   
> Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: 0
>   No numbers are entered except 0

My code currently fulfills the requirements of the question but I'd like to cover all of my bases. With a very basic knowledge of Java, is there a way I can check the `nextInt` in my while statement to see if:

1. The number series doesn't end with a 0. In my testing, the program just seems to stop (note my debugging output in my While statement). I am guessing there isn't a simple way to do this, thus we are to use 0 as a sentinel, but I figured I would ask.
2. If only the Enter key is pressed.  When I do that in NetBeans the prompt moves to the next line, I would like to include a message notifying the user that nothing was entered and to enter an integer.

My Code:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package positivenegative;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PositiveNegative {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Welcome message
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Number Averagererer.");
            // Yes I'm aware "Averagererer" isn't a word
        System.out.println("Be sure to enter a 0 at the end");
        System.out.println("or the program will not work.");
        System.out.print("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: ");

        // Initialize variables
        int number, totalPositive=0, totalNegative=0, counter=0;  
        double average=0;

        // Process the entered variables and sort/calculate them        
        while ((number = input.nextInt()) != 0){ // Continues if number isn't 0
            System.out.println(number); //debugging to see what the nextInt is doing
            // Adds to positive  
            if (number > 0){
                totalPositive++;
                counter++;
                average = (average + number);         
                }
            // Adds to negative
            else{
                System.out.println(number);
                totalNegative++;
                counter++;        
                average = (average + number);
                }
        }

    // Output message if the user only enters "0"
    if (counter == 0){
        System.out.println("No numbers were entered except 0");
        }                    

    // Output message with calculated data from input
    else{
        double total = average;
        average = (average / counter);
        System.out.println("The number of positives is: " + totalPositive);
        System.out.println("The number of negatives is: " + totalNegative);
        System.out.println("The total is: " + total);
        System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not really understand what you are asking for. Part A:  Do you want your app to accept 0 as an input? Part B: Do you want your app to accept any character for input?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
package positivenegative;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PositiveNegative
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        // Welcome message
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Number Averagererer.");
        // Yes I'm aware "Averagererer" isn't a word
        System.out.println("Be sure to enter a 0 at the end");
        System.out.println("or the program will not work.");
        System.out.print("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: ");

        // Initialize variables
        int number = -1;
        int totalPositive = 0;
        int totalNegative = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        double average = 0;
        String line = "";
        while (line.isEmpty())
        {
            line = readLine();
            if (line.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("Line is empty. Enter number!");
            }
        }

        try (final Scanner input = new Scanner(line))
        {
            // Process the entered line and sort/calculate them
            while (input.hasNextInt())
            {
                number = input.nextInt();
                if (number == 0)
                {
                    // stop if number is 0
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("number: " + number);// TODO: remove
                // Adds to positive
                if (number > 0)
                {
                    totalPositive++;
                }
                // Adds to negative
                else
                {
                    totalNegative++;
                }
                counter++;
                average = (average + number);
            }

            // Output message if the user only enters "0"
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("No numbers were entered except 0");
            }

            // Output message with calculated data from input
            else
            {
                final double total = average;
                average = (average / counter);
                System.out.println("The number of positives is: " + totalPositive);
                System.out.println("The number of negatives is: " + totalNegative);
                System.out.println("The total is: " + total);
                System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
            }
        }
    }

    private static String readLine()
    {
        try
        {
            final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            final String s = br.readLine();
            return s;
        } catch (final IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

With your scanner, you *could* use `input.hasNextInt()` to test if there are more numbers, but it will block until there are. More details on the blocking can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873134/hasnext-when-does-it-block-and-why).