# How to make scanner block in java

Tags: java, sockets, blocking

I am making a multithreaded server-client app where every client has its own dedicated thread. Server and client communicate using a specific message format that ends with "END\r\n". For this purpose, I thought of using Scanner class and its useDellimiter method. Here is the code

```
     private static String getMessage(InputStream input) throws IOException {
           Scanner n = new Scanner(input); 
           n.useDelimiter("END\r\n");
           while(!n.hasNext()) {} 
           return n.next(); 

     }
```

The problem  I ran into is that n.next() doesn't block if the message isn't available instead it throws an exception. I fixed this with basic polling with this while loop, it works, but that seems like bad practice. Can I make n.next() block? Is there a better way of achieving what I want without using the Scanner class?

Comment: Maybe the thread [hasNext() - when does it block and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16874004/10386912) helps

Comment: `hasNext()` and `next()` always blocks unless the stream has been closed in which case there is no more data.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a self contained program which shows that `hasNext()` blocks as expected when there is no input. It blocks until the stream is closed at which point there is no more data.

```
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(0);
    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", ss.getLocalPort());
    Socket s2 = ss.accept();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
    scanner.hasNext();
```

blocks, and a thread dump shows

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=578.13ms elapsed=12.74s tid=0x000001eda6aee000 nid=0x6220 runnable  [0x0000004848afe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.base@11.0.1/Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(java.base@11.0.1/SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.1/SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.1/SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(java.base@11.0.1/StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(java.base@11.0.1/StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(java.base@11.0.1/StreamDecoder.java:178)
    - locked <0x00000007ffc9b270> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(java.base@11.0.1/InputStreamReader.java:185)
    at java.io.Reader.read(java.base@11.0.1/Reader.java:189)
    at java.util.Scanner.readInput(java.base@11.0.1/Scanner.java:882)
    at java.util.Scanner.hasNext(java.base@11.0.1/Scanner.java:1446)
    at A.main(A.java:33)
```